# How to insert a SQLite record with a datetime set to 'now' in Android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, content-values

Say, we have a table created as:

```
create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, created_date date)
```

To insert a record, I'd use

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("date_created", "");
long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

But how to set the date_created column to **now**?  To make it clear, the

```
initialValues.put("date_created", "datetime('now')");
```

Is not the right solution.  It just sets the column to "datetime('now')" text.

Comment: One problem here is that Android uses SQLite for the DB.  You can set a column to a certain type but that just sets the columns 'affinity'.  SQLite will let you put any value in any column regardless of how it's declared.  To SQLite putting the string 'date' in anywhere is pretty okay.  sqlite.org has a more thorough explanation.

I'm voting up e-satis's answer below, that's how I do it (specifically the Java way).

Answer (score 199):

You cannot use the datetime function using the Java wrapper "ContentValues". Either you can use :

- SQLiteDatabase.execSQL so you can enter a raw SQL query.

  ```
  mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE+" VALUES (null, datetime()) ");
  ```
- Or the java date time capabilities :

  ```
  // set the format to sql date time
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
  Date date = new Date();
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
  initialValues.put("date_created", dateFormat.format(date));
  long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  ```

Comment: Please reformat code as 'Code Sample'.  Otherwise good answer.

Comment: is that a java.util.Date or a java.sql.Date?

Comment: java.util.Date, but I'm sure you can do It with java.sql.Date date as well.

Answer (score 45):

In my code I use `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the type and constraint of the column.

In your case your table definition would be

```
create table notes (
  _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
  created_date date default CURRENT_DATE
)
```

Answer (score 35):

**Method 1**

```
CURRENT_TIME – Inserts only time
CURRENT_DATE – Inserts only date
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP – Inserts both time and date

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Method 2**

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(username, created_at) 
            VALUES('ravitamada', 'datetime()'");
```

**Method 3**
Using java Date functions

```
private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
}

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put('username', 'ravitamada');
values.put('created_at', getDateTime());
// insert the row
long id = db.insert('users', null, values);
```

Comment: Curious, can you show how you would switch the resulting string back to a DATE  object?

Comment: @erik Can you give more information, I am not exactly getting what you said.

Comment: so above you are taking a Date object and converting it to a string to be placed in a sqlite column.. but when you pull that string from the database, how do you convert it back to a Date object?

Comment: @erik SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); formatter.parse(created_at);

Comment: @erik I think we don't required to convert back string to date because in DB we have datetime column so it will save as datetime.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple options you can use:

1. You could try using the string "(DATETIME('now'))" instead.
2. Insert the datetime yourself, ie with System.currentTimeMillis()
3. When creating the SQLite table, specify a default value for the created_date column as the current date time.
4. Use [SQLiteDatabase.execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) to insert directly.

Comment: Number 1 doesn't work (at least not when using `ContentValues` and `update()`, it just puts the string `DATETIME('now')` in the column.

Comment: The second one has problems with timezones. I inserted a record with a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and later used `System.currentTimeMillis()` to update. I see an hour difference.

Comment: @sooniln  Have you verified that (DATETIME('now')) will indeed insert the current datetime?

Comment: If you want to add local datetime , try to use  "datetime('now','localtime')" instead

Answer (score 7):

To me, the problem looks like you're sending `"datetime('now')"` as a string, rather than a value.

My thought is to find a way to grab the current date/time and send it to your database as a date/time value, or find a way to use SQLite's built-in `(DATETIME('NOW'))` parameter

Check out the anwsers at [this SO.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now) - they might lead you in the right direction.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function of java that is:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(Constants.DATE, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In this way, in your db you save a number.
This number could be interpreted in this way:

```
    DateFormat dateF = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    String data = dateF.format(new Date(l));
```

Instead of l into new Date(l), you shoul insert the number into the column of date.
So, you have your date.
For example i save in my db this number : 1332342462078
But when i call the method above i have this result: 21-mar-2012 16.07.42

Answer (score 3):

Based on @e-satis answer I created a private method on my "DBTools" class so adding current date is now really easy:

```
...
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
...
        private String getNow(){
            // set the format to sql date time
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            return dateFormat.format(date);
        }
...
```

Use it now like this: `values.put("lastUpdate", getNow());`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me perfect:

```
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE, geo.getReceiveDate().getTime());
```

Save your date as a long.

Answer (score 1):

This code example may do what you want:

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=413

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the field is not marked as 'not null' at the same time as you are trying to insert a default time stamp using the expression "(DATETIME('now'))"