# Add Text From EditText to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, button, android-edittext

I want to make it so that when I click a Button, it takes the text from the `EditText` and adds it to an `SQLiteDatabase`. I've read it somewhere before, but I forgot how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the following functions:
To implement the eveent Listener :
[onClick()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

To get Text from textedit
[getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29)

To add data into SQLite :
[insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.content.ContentValues%29)

Docs are the best guide....

Comment: Actually, it won't let me put in TABLE_NAME as my String where. Here's the code: ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 et.getText();
                 db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
                    additem.dismiss();
                    et.setText("");
                }
            });`

Comment: Have you created the table before ? . Also the insert() returns rowid of the inserted row . assign a variable to it and see what it has...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754684/how-to-insert-a-sqlite-record-with-a-datetime-set-to-now-in-android-application :a good post that shows how to insert data into SQlite.

Comment: I have created the table in the DataHelper class, and I have a SimpleCursorAdapter before this.

Comment: Actually, I decided to try `et.getText().toString()`.

Comment: I'll need help with the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

How about grabbing the text, converting it to a  String and putting it into the query

```
String TableName = "ComplicatedTableNameHere";  
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextIDhere); 
String editTextString1 = editText1.getText().toString();
```

**BROKEN DOWN**

```
String TableName = "ComplicatedTableNameHere";            
    //sets the table name as a string so you can refer to TableName instead of writing out your table name everytime

EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextIDhere); 
    //gets the text from your edit text fieldfield 
    //editText1 = your edit text name
    //EditTextIDhere = the id of your text field

String editTextString1 = editText1.getText().toString();  
    //sets the edit text as a string
    //editText1 is the name of the Edit text from the (EditText) we defined above
    //editTextString1 = the string name you will refer to in future
```

**then use**

```
       /* Insert data to a Table*/
       myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
         + TableName
         + " (Column_Name, Column_Name2, Column_Name3, Column_Name4)"
         + " VALUES ( "+EditTextString1+", 'Column_Value2','Column_Value3','Column_Value4');");
```

Hope this helps some what...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
mydatebase.execSQL(
      "INSERT INTO xxx (name,number,age) VALUES ('"+YOUR_STRING_DATA+"',123456789,22)"
);
```

Comment: This is a dangerous way as it may lead to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It also doesn't answer the the question i.e. how to get the text from a UI component - please update your answer