# How to insert current date in sqlite from android application

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I want to insert current date in SQLite database datetime type field.
How can I do this?

**UPDATE** : Using `mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (datetime()) ");`

I am able to insert like `date_created=2012-10-10 13:02:08` and I want this format `10 Oct 2012 12:48` how to achive this?

Answer (score 10):

I prefer the following ways to get it done:

1. Create the table with a default settings to put current datetime
   automatically. For example:

   ```
   ColumnName DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ```
2. Create `SimpleDateFormat` and convert current date into SQL format
   string. For example:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   String strDate = sdf.format(new Date());

   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put("ColumnName", strDate);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (datetime()) ");
```

check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/819605/1434631

Comment: Thanks for the response I used it and it is giving result like date_created=2012-10-10 13:02:08 and I want this format 10 Oct 2012 12:48 how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ContentValues coloumnVlues = new ContentValues();
   //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date();
   coloumnVlues.put("fname", fname);

   // inserted date in database like May 31, 2013 10:42:53 AM it's simulator datetime
   coloumnVlues.put("created_date", DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(). format(date));
```

their is no need to use SimpleDateFormat.

you get datetime from database the example  given in below link

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html