# How to add datetime function in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert a SQLite record with a datetime set to ‘now’ in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754684/how-to-insert-a-sqlite-record-with-a-datetime-set-to-now-in-android-applicatio)

i'm developing an app which stores name, password etc to the database. And i also want to store current date and time to the database and retrieve back later. I'm unable to crack how to store date and time in SQLite database. Should i use datetime function?? If yes how to add it in my proceeding example. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class DBAdapter{public static final String ROWID = "_id";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "primus_db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "user_db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table user_db (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, "
        + "email text not null, "
        + "password text not null," + "type text not null );";
private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

/**
 * 
 */
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.DBHelper = new DBAdapter.DatabaseHelper(this.context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// ---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

// ---insert a contact into the database---
public long insertContact(String name, String email, String password,
        String type) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(EMAIL, email);
    initialValues.put(PASSWORD, password);
    initialValues.put(TYPE, type);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// ---retrieves all the contacts---
public Cursor getAllContacts() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROWID, NAME, EMAIL,
            PASSWORD, TYPE }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow different ways. You can use  `DATETIME('NOW')` while inserting timestamps into the records, can't you?  Or you can use this while creating table.

```
time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

where time is the column which takes current time.

For more details refer [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have plan to reuse that date/time data like "between start date and end date" function or something like that, I would recommend using `timestamp` like `DATETIME('NOW')` and use `long datatype`. Or if it is just for record, you can use `currentDateTime.getTime())` and use `text datatype`.