# Insert/Update Proper date in SQLLite Table in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How to insert a proper date value using `SQLiteDatabase.update/SQLiteDatabase.insert`.
The problem appears to be that ContentValues takes only Strings as input of its pairs.

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754684/how-to-insert-a-sqlite-record-with-a-datetime-set-to-now-in-android-applicatio)

For quick reference, this is the solution provided in that question:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("date_created", dateFormat.format(date));
long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

The problem with this solution is, it doesnot insert a proper 'Date' value into a Date column, but inserts the DAte as a text.
I know this because when i retrieve the data (select) and do date operations on it, it doen't work.

(TO be precise, `datetime(DATE_COLUMN,'localtime')` returns null value)

Can someone help me with my problem? I have already wasted hours :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support a `Date` type as seen in some other DBMS. Instead dates are stored either as text in a well known format or as numeric using the unix epoch.

The datetime function reads text in different formats, including `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and returns them as text in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so in your case, `datetime` will return what is already stored in the database in the same format, but will change timezone to localtime (assuming it is in utc before).

Android will make the result of `datetime` available through `Cursor.getString`. You can get the Date object back by using `DateFormat.parse`.

The following should more or less work (without knowing your database schema):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
[...]
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{"datetime("+DATE_COLUMN+",'localtime')"}, null, null, null. null, null);
cursor.moveToNext();
Date parsed = dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(0));
```

Reference: https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.. m too exausted and tired now(its 3 am here) will try again after some sleep  and post a reply. thanks

Comment: I agree with lama.
The way i store date in my app is by storing the string of date.toString(). according to Android Developers it stores is in the following format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy".
It includes the time zone.