# Inserting to db with rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm just learning Android. I have working piece of code that uses ContentValues:

My constants:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "numbers";
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NUMBER = "number";
```

This way I create table:

```
db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + COL_ID +
            " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COL_NUMBER +
            " integer not null );" );
```

And this way I add values to the table:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put( SQLHelper.COL_NUMBER, 1 );
long id = db.insert( SQLHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values );
```

It works, but when I replace inserting with rawQuery it doesn't insert to the table anymore:

```
db.rawQuery( "INSERT INTO " + SQLHelper.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES( NULL, 1 )", null );
```

where do I make a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> db.rawQuery --> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.
>
> db.execSQL--> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

- [See Here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: yes, I have read that, but does it mean that it doesn't run the sql statement on the database side, but only creates Cursor object and returns it?

Comment: I have found a topic on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470739/how-to-use-rawquery-to-insert-a-record?rq=1 and there some guy says to use "execSQL". But the topic is like 1 year old so it just changed during the time or what?

Comment: I've got another solution, but I don't understand why it works. I changed it to: db.rawQuery( "INSERT INTO " + SQLHelper.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES( NULL, 1 );", null ).moveToFirst(); but the documentation doesn't say anything in the moveToFirst() that it executes anything...