# SQLite: Order by 'insertOrderinDB'

Tags: android, sqlite

i need to know how to make a select with the insert order in DB without making any index field by my own . May be this posible?

And , the insertion order in a transaction is linear-mode? (first insert sentences -> first insert )

**DB CREATION**:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SONGS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SONGS (" +
        "LIST_ID int NOT NULL, " +
        "PLAY_ID int NOT NULL, " + //ID of the song in the list
        "SONG_ID int NOT NULL, " + //ID of the song
        "TITLE varchar(200) NOT NULL," +
        "TIME int NOT NULL, " +
        "PROVIDER int NOT NULL, " +
        "PROVIDER_ID varchar(200) NOT NULL, " +
        "SONG_STATE int NOT NULL, " +
        "PRIMARY KEY (LIST_ID,PLAY_ID));";
```

And then

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SONGS);
```

Comment: you mean without altering the table structure?

Comment: without adding any else field

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _ID

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS modified question ;)

Comment: and `TIME` is not insertion time?

Comment: no , time is duration of a song. I'm sure that i cant use the fields which are in the table , cause they have different meanings that you can think about them , truth me .

Comment: then i think there is no way. how about new table, can you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite tables have a "secret" column called `ROWID` the value of which increases as you add rows.  It can serve as a proxy for "order entered into table".  `ROWID` is basically a "free" auto-incrementing integer primary key column for the table.

Note that by definition SQL databases have no notion of row ordering.  While I would be surprised if the behavior of `ROWID` every changed in SQLite (since it's existence and behavior is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)), as a rule if you want to retrieve rows in an ordered fashion in SQL databases you're responsible for storing the ordering information yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by _id
```

should do, given the autoincrement nature of the id.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _ID:

Answer (score 0):

The best-practices method of sorting rows by the temporal order in which they have been inserted is to use a timestamp column which is assigned as a default value the date-time corresponding to "now", as the row is being inserted.  This is easy to do in SQLite.

[sqlite database default time value 'now'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now)