# SQLite CURRENT_TIMESTAMP always 1970-01-01

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following defining a table:

```
CREATE TABLE players(playerid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                     name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                     added DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` relentlessly inserts `1970-01-01`.  I am loosely aware of the significance of this date and how some timestamps are a positive/negative offset from it; however, from what I've read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now), my  default timestamp should use the current time/date, as is suggests.  Also, should a timestamp not include the time (from 1970 or otherwise)?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had an epiphany and realised I was being an idiot. I am using Java to connect to the database and was using `resultSet.getDate("added")`, which apparently is not suited to this purpose, and returns `1970-01-01`.  `getString("added")` confirmed my mistake, and returned exactly what I wanted to see :)