# How to get date value from SQLite in java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a simple table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [InformacjeZDziekanatu] (
  [_id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [DataWstawienia] DATE NOT NULL, 
  [DataModyfikacji] DATE NOT NULL, 
  [Tresc] VARCHAR2 NOT NULL);
```

In my application only what I want to do is to get value of `DataWstawienia` column.
I am using such method:

```
try {
    ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("select * from InformacjeZDziekanatu order by _id desc limit 5");
    int id;
    Date dataWst;
    Date dataMod;
    String tresc;               

    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
            result.next();
            Object[] lista = new Object[4];
            id = result.getInt("_id");
            dataWst = result.getDate("DataWstawienia");
            dataMod = result.getDate("DataModyfikacji");
            tresc = result.getString("Tresc");
            lista[0] = id;
            lista[1] = dataWst;
            lista[2] = dataMod;
            lista[3] = tresc;
            dane[j] = lista;

    }
}
```

All dates in `DataWstawienia` column are today's dates but using this method above I get 1970-01-01 date all the time.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you save the dates? 1970 means it is interpreted as 0.

Comment: I've got it! Problem was in lines:   dataWst=result.getDate("DataWstawienia");
dataMod = result.getDate("DataModyfikacji"); Instead of this i should use : result.getString("DataWstawienia"); and change type of dataWst to a String. Now everything works correctly.

Comment: the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829362/sqlite-current-timestamp-always-1970-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLIte does not have a DATE data type. Dates need to either be stored as integers (number of seconds since Unix Epoch is common) or as ISO 8601 times (e.g. 2013-10-01T12:12:12). If you say `DATE` in your SQLite schema you will store values as strings.  Your solution of changing the type of `dateWst` to `String` acknowledges the fact that you are storing dates as strings and not as an internal date type.