# how to get the ordered query in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I insert some data into test table.

```
C:\>  sqlite3 e:\\test.db
sqlite> create table test(code TEXT,content  numeric);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('x',3);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('x',1.5);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('x',1);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('y',9);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('y',3);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('y',2);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('y',12.3);
sqlite> insert into test(code,content)values('y',11.5);
```

how can i get the ordered output as the following ?
`select * from test group by code order by content;`can not get it.
`select * from test order by content;`neither.

```
x|1
x|1.5
x|3
y|2
y|3
y|9
y|11.5
y|12.3
```

Comment: If you want to have the results in time order, like most recent first, or oldest first, then you need to add an automatic timestamp to your table.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461851/how-to-have-an-automatic-timestamp-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by multiple criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY code, content;
```