# Created at column for ORMLite

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, ormlite

A 'modified at' column can be created in ORMLite by using the `version` annotation, as described at http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#index-time-row-last-modified.

Is it possible to define a 'created at' column, which is automatically populated with the current timestamp but unmodified thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for SQLite:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL", readOnly = true, canBeNull = false)
private Date created_at;
```

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726207/ormlite-column-with-default), readOnly is required so that ORMLite does not try to insert a row with a null timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to define a 'created at' column, which is automatically populated with the current timestamp but unmodified thereafter?

Yes it can, but this is a per-database operation so the solution depends on which database type you are using.  See this answer about Sqlite specifically: [How to have an automatic timestamp in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461851/how-to-have-an-automatic-timestamp-in-sqlite)

The following might work although I'm not sure about the *type* of the field.  It may have to be a Sql `java.sql.Timestamp` or something:

```
@DatabaseFile(columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL")
private Date createDate;
```

For more information see Sqlite's [documentation on date-time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: When I define the column using  ```@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.TIME_STAMP, columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL")```, I get:
 ```[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed:```. What ORMLite must be doing is trying to  explicitly insert a NULL value into the field. Adding ```persisted = false``` to the annotation avoids this, but then the column isn't being created on table creation. Is there a way to create the column, but to also tell ORMLite to ignore that column on INSERT?

Comment: This should be another question @TrentDi.

Comment: New [question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726207/ormlite-column-with-default)