# ORMLite column with default

Tags: null, sql-insert, ormlite

I have a non null column defined with a default:

`@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.TIME_STAMP, columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL")
private Date createdDate;`

When trying to save a row with the `createdDate` field unset, I get the following error:

`[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL] A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed:`

ORMLite is probably trying to explicitly insert a `NULL` value into the field. Adding `persisted = false` to the annotation avoids this, but then the column isn't being created on table creation.

Is there a way to create the column, but to also tell ORMLite to ignore that column on INSERT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create the column, but to also tell ORMLite to ignore that column on INSERT?

What you were missing is the [`readOnly = true` setting for `@DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#readOnly()).  To quote the javadocs:

> Set this to be true (default false) if this field is a read-only field. This field will be returned by queries however it will be ignored during insert/create statements.  [ just added: ] This can be used to represent create or modification dates with the values being generated by the database.

I just used the following field definition (with H2 at least) and it worked fine:

```
@DatabaseField(columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL",
    readOnly = true, canBeNull = false)
private Date createdDate;
```

You don't need to specify the `dataType` and if you do, your field should be a `Timestamp` type I believe.  Btw, this feature was missing from the online documentation which I just rectified.