# How to update the timestamp in SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, timestamp, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my Andoid App. I have three rows, ID, DATA and DATE, where DATE is filled by SQLite by using the `TIMESTAMP` as follows `CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $DATE TEXT NOT NULL, $DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`.

It works fine for me. But when I update the `DATA` row, the timestamp does not update with. I update the `DATA` ad follows:

```
fun updateData(id: String, data: String): Boolean {
    db.update(TABLE, ContentValues().apply {
        put(DATA, data)
    }, "$ID = ?", arrayOf(id))
    return true
}
```

After update, the timestamp stays the same. How can I update the timesamp after each DATA updating?

Comment: Read up on triggers: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605044/549372) ... `DEFAULT` only applies to `INSERT`.

Comment: Could append current_timestamp to your string 'data' before running update so that you get the current timestamp each update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the update by changing

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $DATA TEXT, $DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);")
}
```

to

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $DATA TEXT, $DATE TEXT;")
}
```

and then I defined a variable to pick up the current time

```
private var date = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm").format(Date())
```

and added it to `update` mathod:

```
fun updateData(id: String, data: String): Boolean {
    db.update(TABLE, ContentValues().apply {
    put(DATA, data)
    put(DATE, date)
    }, "$ID = ?", arrayOf(id))
    return true
}
```

That's all. Now it updates the date for each change/modification.

Answer (score 2):

Create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON tab
WHEN old.data <> new.data
BEGIN
  UPDATE tab
  SET date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE id = old.id; 
END;
```

Replace `tab` with your table's name.
This will be executed every time the column `data` is updated.
You must execute this statement in the `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s class `onCreate()` method right after the `CREATE` statement of the table.
After you make the changes in the class, uninstall the app from the device where you test it so the database is deleted and rerun.

Comment: Hey bro, probebly your solution could also help me to fix my problem. But I preffered to do it otherwise. Please see my answer. P.S. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I thought you wanted everything to be done by the db engine. Anyway: **don't** use this format: `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm` to store the dates. SQLite is not that flexible with dates. Store it as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` which is comparable and can be formatted later to suit your needs.