# How do I create an updated "date" field using SQLITE 3?

Tags: sql

I am writing a program to help me keep track of my day to day life, and I want one of the fields to be a "date" field that will automatically update.  What specifically do I do in SQLITE 3?  Something like....

```
create table day_to_day(
date field
miles_ran INTEGER
food_eaten TEXT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CREATE TABLE day_to_day(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 t TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 miles_ran INTEGER
 food_eaten TEXT
);
```

which would give you a column called t with the type TIMESTAMP, as a alternative you could also use this:

```
CREATE TABLE day_to_day(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 t DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
 miles_ran INTEGER
 food_eaten TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this :

```
CREATE TABLE table_test (
   ...
   date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE table_test (
   ...
   date DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
);
```

This is a good reference : [sqlite database default time value 'now'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now)

Answer (score 0):

You can read what the docs have to say about it: [SQLite datatypes, scroll to section 1.2](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

The gist of it is, you can either use `TEXT`, `REAL`, or `INTEGER`, and then use the corresponding [Date/Time function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to access it.