# How to add column to database with default

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, date, create-table

I have a database that I'm trying to add a column to. This column should hold information of the type `timestamp`, and I want every row to have the same timestamp (the current time) when I'm done.

I currently have tried:

```py
cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN time timestamp DEFAULT ?''', (datetime.datetime.utcnow(),))
```

Which results in `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`.

So then I tried:

```py
cursor.execute(f'''ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN time timestamp DEFAULT {datetime.datetime.utcnow()}''')
```

Which results in `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "-": syntax error`.

Also, doing

```py
cursor.execute(f'''ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP''')
```

results in `sqlite3.OperationalError: Cannot add a column with non-constant default`.

How can I add the new column and set the values in that column? (Either through `DEFAULT`, or some other mechanism.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite database default time value 'now'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first add the new column and then update every existing row in the table to the desired value:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN time;
UPDATE my_table SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: I learned the "timestamp" from [this](https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-date-and-datetime/) which was apparently wrong and I should be using the `TEXT` value for my purposes.

Comment: Hmm... when I change it to `TEXT`, my formatting no longer works like it used to - I'll have to look into this. It's very odd that an undocumented type would work but the documented type would not.

Comment: I figured it out - SQLite does have a ["timestamp" type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters). It is used for the converter to Python's `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: @ProQ Small correction: SQLite does not have a "timestamp" type. "timestamp" is an unknown type and therefore is defined as "numeric" in SQLite. Instead of "timestamp" you could also write "kmsnfrwtx" with the same result. Also, those are not types, but type affinities. Check this out: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of setting value as default to the column

Answer (score 14):

SQLite does not allow adding a new column with a non-constant value. So this:

```
alter table my_table add column my_time timestamp default current_timestamp;
```

... generates error:

```
Cannot add a column with non-constant default
```

A simple option would be to recreate the table. Assuming that you have single column called `id`, that would look like:

```
create table my_table_new(
    id int primary key, 
     my_time timestamp default current_timestamp
);

insert into my_table_new(id) select id from my_table;
drop table my_table;  -- back it up first!
alter table my_table_new rename to my_table;
```

Comment: but, data will be gone if drop.

Comment: @Eric The second query copies all data from the old table to the new data, so no data is lost.

Comment: Note that this procedure may trigger foreign key constraints and triggers! If you want a foolproof method, read the section "7. Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes" at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: @FWDekker exact link to named section with anchor: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html#making_other_kinds_of_table_schema_changes