# sqlite3.OperationalError: default DATE value of column is not constant

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6, default, datetime-format

I am creating a sqlite3 table that accepts records from a server.  There should be one date/text column that also has a `datetime` DEFAULT value, so I can sync a record which times differ from the server's record.

I found a solution on this forum from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200309/sqlite-database-default-time-value-now).  The problem is it gives me the following error on executing the table creation script: `sqlite3.OperationalError: default value of column [updated_at] is not constant`.

Table is created:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_tb(\
                    emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
                    emp_names TEXT NOT NULL,\
                    emp_number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,\
                    ent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,\
                    active INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",\
                    updated_at TEXT NULL DEFAULT (datetime("now", "localtime")),\
                    syncstatus INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "0")')
```

Should I create a trigger? or How can I have a default value in format `("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")` in case the update misses a spot?

Comment: Try it with single quotes (`'`) on the `datetime` arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggested solution solved it.  I also had to escape your suggested single quotes to make it work:  ```updated_at TEXT NULL DEFAULT (datetime(\'now\', \'localtime\')),\```.  If you make your comment the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes (`'`) for the datetime options. As mentioned in the comments, they will have to be escaped (because the query is delimited with single quotes).